# Date/time option values for Ecommerce steps

Tags: google-analytics, ecommerce

I'd like to track "pickup date/time" as part of a checkout process in order to report on popular days/times. I'm currently looking at doing so via a "step option" as part of Enhanced Ecommerce, but I'm unsure of what format to use.

Do Enhanced Ecommerce "steps options" support date values and, if so, what format should they be supplied in?